# Prove that a self-complementary graph has radius $2$ and diameter $2$ or $3$

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that a self-complementary graph has radius $2$ and diameter $2$ or $3$.

I think that is one of the well-known properties of self-complementary graphs, but I am having some troubles trying to prove it. The facts that, if $G\cong \bar G$, then both graphs $G$ and $\bar G$ are connected, and that, for any graph, if $rad(G)\geq3$ then $rad(\bar G)\leq 2$, and that if $diam(G)\geq3$ then $diam(\bar G)\leq3$, should make the proof quite easier, but I don't know how to develop it. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties you list directly imply that a self-complementary graph cannot have radius $3$ or higher, and it cannot have diameter $4$ or higher.

The only thing that remains to show is that it can't have radius $1$ (the fact that the diameter can't be $1$ follows as a corollary). And (excluding the trivial example of a singleton), that can't happen either, as radius $1$ means there is a node which is connected to all other nodes, meaning the complement is not connected.

Comment: The self-complementary graph of order $1$ has radius and diameter $0$.

Comment: @bof You're right. You might as well add that as a comment to the question as well, though.

Comment: But I don't see clearly why these properties imply that a s-c graph cannot have radius $\geq3$. Why can't we have $rad(G)=5$ and $rad(\bar G)=2$? Which fact of an s-c graph is acting as a restriction?

Comment: @Gibbs Because it is self-complementary. $G$ and $\bar G$ must have the same radius, as they are essentially the same graph.

Comment: Didn't know. So $diam(G)$ and $diam(\bar G)$ are also equal. Then after proving radius can't be one, we are done with the proof.

Comment: @Gibbs Yup. That's all there is to it.